# How to combine multiple for loops into a single generator python

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

I'm on a Python project that uses this for-loop all over the place

```
for year in yearsindex:
    for month in monthindex:
        for hour in hourindex:
            for node in nodeindex:
                dosomething(year, month, hour, node)
```

I was wondering if there was a way to combine all of the iterators into a single iterator to be more readable

Something in the form of

```
for (year, month, hour, node) in combinediterator:
    dosomething(year, month, hour, node)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
for year, month, hour, node in itertools.product(
        yearsindex, monthindex, hourindex, nodeindex):
    dosomething(year, month, hour, node)
```

You can see that cramming all that onto a single logical line isn't really a readability improvement. There are several ways to make it an improvement. For example, if you can avoid unpacking the tuples the iterator gives you, or if you can put the arguments to `itertools.product` in a list and unpack them with `*args`:

```
for arg_tuple in itertools.product(*indexes):
    dosomething(*arg_tuple)
```

If the loop body is longer than just one line of `dosomething`, you also get the benefit of decreased indentation. With a short loop body, that doesn't matter much.

Comment: great answer although imho this is not at all more readable than the other method

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Yeah, cramming all that onto a line isn't really better than the nested loops. I've added some more text on how to make it prettier.

Comment: My initial reaction was to do this with a generator.  IMO this is the better solution.

Comment: is there any chance you could clarify how the (`*`indexes) works? I've never seen the '`*`' notation before. What does it do?

Comment: @Grant: It's argument unpacking. There's a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters) on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just wrap it in a function definition in a form of a generator, like so:

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l2 = [4,5,6]
>>> l3 = [7,8,9]
>>>
>>> 
>>> def comb_gen(a,b,c):
        for x in a:
            for y in b:
                for z in c:
                    yield (x,y,z)


>>> 
>>> for x,y,z in comb_gen(l1,l2,l3):
        print(x,y,z)


1 4 7
1 4 8
1 4 9
1 5 7
1 5 8
1 5 9
1 6 7
1 6 8
1 6 9
2 4 7
2 4 8
2 4 9
2 5 7
2 5 8
2 5 9
2 6 7
2 6 8
2 6 9
3 4 7
3 4 8
3 4 9
3 5 7
3 5 8
3 5 9
3 6 7
3 6 8
3 6 9
```

Comment: great answer as this will allow him to maintain the understandability of what the operation is doing as well

Comment: @JoranBeasley ..Thanks for support..although I was a bit worried to post it as answer as I was thinking I might be re-inventing the wheel with `itertools.product` ... I hope I did not

Comment: Unfortunately, you did. I think this just looks more readable because of the shortened variable names you used.